# Cannot run bundle command on remote server from local computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I've create a script that copies a tar file to a remote server, do some stuffs then runs:

```sh
[..]

kill $(lsof -i :3000 -t)

# Bundle up
cd $DIR && \
  bundle install && \
  RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile && \
  rails s -e production -p 3000 -d
```

Should I run this on the remote server directly `./my-script.sh param`, all is well. It does not work when I call this script from my local computer. It complains about

> ./my-script.sh: line 18: bundle: command not found

When I ran `which bundle` on remote server I got back:

```sh
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/bundle
```

Using the above in my script I get tons of errors. How to get pass that error when calling script from local computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set all ruby and bundler env variables to use `bundle exec`

if rvm is used you should load it:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

try to know all env for rvm on your server under ruby user by:
`rvm env`

it runs like  `ssh example.com   < ./bundle.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash +ex
# bundle.sh

export PATH="/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4@global/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.4/bin:$PATH"
export GEM_HOME='/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4'
export GEM_PATH='/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4@global'
export MY_RUBY_HOME='/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.4'
export IRBRC='/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.4/.irbrc'
unset MAGLEV_HOME
unset RBXOPT
export RUBY_VERSION='ruby-2.6.4'
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

export RAILS_ENV=production

cd /path/ && bundle exec rails db:migrate:status
cd $DIR && \
  bundle install && \
  bundle exec rake assets:precompile && \
  rails s -e production -p 3000 -d
```

Comment: it works ok  ```ssh example.com   < ./bundle.sh```

Comment: Let me ask, we do you put that script?

Comment: Could you provide an example from the code I have?

Comment: Ok it worked but was not clear. I had to copy the contents from `rvm env` into my script for it to work. What's the purpose of your first code?

Comment: source ```"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"``` - loads rvm 
Of course ```rvm env``` should be get from server under ruby user 

And it's better to use the same env for all bundle and rails commands
```export RAILS_ENV=production``` for whole bundle script is better than use env inline for some commands only and in different ways.